# Firebase function return batch of updates error Cannot modify a WriteBatch that has been committed

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

this is my code:

```
exports.updateUserName = functions.firestore
  .document("users/{userId}")
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const newValue = change.after.data().name;
    const previousValue = change.before.data().name;
    const userID = context.params.userId;
    var batch = admin.firestore().batch();
    if (newValue != previousValue) {

      //Update author in sets/{set_id}/author
       admin
        .firestore()
        .collection("sets")
        .where("authorId", "==", userID)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
          if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
             querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
              batch.update(doc.ref,{ "author": newValue });
            });
          }
        }),

    //Update author in courses/{course_id}/author
      admin
        .firestore()
        .collection("courses")
        .where("authorId", "==", userID)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
          if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
             querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
              batch.update(doc.ref,{ "author": newValue });
            });
          }
        })
    }
   return batch.commit().then(() => {
    console.log("commited")
  });
  });
```

So I want to update two different documents. I think I have to do this with batch().
But I get the Error:

```
Error: Cannot modify a WriteBatch that has been committed.
    at WriteBatch.verifyNotCommitted (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:117:19)
    at WriteBatch.update (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:313:14)
    at /workspace/index.js:84:21
    at QuerySnapshot.forEach (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:748:22)
    at /workspace/index.js:83:33
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

This is the first time Im working with batch or have to update 2 documents with one cloud function.
What am I doin wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait the asynchronous queries are completed and the batch is populated before calling `commit()`. For that you need to [chain the promises](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining) and return this chain in the Cloud Function.

So the following should do the trick (untested):

```
exports.updateUserName = functions.firestore
    .document("users/{userId}")
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
        const newValue = change.after.data().name;
        const previousValue = change.before.data().name;
        const userID = context.params.userId;
        const db = admin.firestore();
        const batch = db.batch();
        if (newValue != previousValue) {

            //Update author in sets/{set_id}/author
            return db
                .collection("sets")
                .where("authorId", "==", userID)
                .get()
                .then((querySnapshot) => {
                    if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
                        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                            batch.update(doc.ref, { "author": newValue });
                        });
                    }

                    return db
                        .collection("courses")
                        .where("authorId", "==", userID)
                        .get();
                })
                .then((querySnapshot) => {
                    if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
                        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                            batch.update(doc.ref, { "author": newValue });
                        });
                    }
                    return batch.commit();
                })
                .then(() => {
                    console.log("commited")
                    return null;
                });
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    });
```

---

Do not forget that there is a 500 docs limit for a batched write. If you know you may go over this limit, you can use `Promise.all()` instead, as follows:

```
exports.updateUserName = functions.firestore
    .document("users/{userId}")
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
        const newValue = change.after.data().name;
        const previousValue = change.before.data().name;
        const userID = context.params.userId;
        const db = admin.firestore();
        var promises = [];
        
        if (newValue != previousValue) {

            //Update author in sets/{set_id}/author
            return db
                .collection("sets")
                .where("authorId", "==", userID)
                .get()
                .then((querySnapshot) => {
                    if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
                        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                            promises.push(doc.ref.update({ "author": newValue }));
                        });
                    }
                    return db
                        .collection("courses")
                        .where("authorId", "==", userID)
                        .get();
                })
                .then((querySnapshot) => {
                    if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
                        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                            promises.push(doc.ref.update({ "author": newValue }));
                        });
                    }
                    return Promise.all(promises);
                })
                .then(() => {
                    console.log("commited")
                    return null;
                });
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    });
```

---

Finally, note this async/await version which is much easier to read:

```
exports.updateUserName = functions.firestore
    .document("users/{userId}")
    .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
        const newValue = change.after.data().name;
        const previousValue = change.before.data().name;
        const userID = context.params.userId;
        const db = admin.firestore();
        const batch = db.batch();
        if (newValue != previousValue) {

            let querySnapshot = await db
                .collection("sets")
                .where("authorId", "==", userID)
                .get();

            if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    batch.update(doc.ref, { "author": newValue });
                });
            }

            querySnapshot = await db
                .collection("courses")
                .where("authorId", "==", userID)

            if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    batch.update(doc.ref, { "author": newValue });
                });
            }

            await batch.commit();
            console.log("commited")
            return null;

        } else {
            return null;
        }
    });
```